# Google Play Console Crash - Identify line number from Stack Trace

Tags: android, widget

I get irregular crashes reported through the Google Play Console. Looking at one of the crashes, it shows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:  at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:120)
    at appname.LW02WidgetProvider.a(Unknown Source:202)
    at es.antonborri.home_widget.e.onUpdate(Unknown Source:24)
    at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:66)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4329)
```

Am I right in assuming that the crash occurred in my LW02WidgetProvider on line 202? This is the relevant code from this part of that file. Line 202 is the setImageViewBitmap:

```
val imageBytes5 = Base64.decode(widgetData.getString("dayfiveIcon", null), Base64.DEFAULT)
val decodedImage5 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes5, 0, imageBytes5.size)
setImageViewBitmap(R.id.lw02_dayfiveIcon, decodedImage5)
```

I'm assuming that widgetData.getString is returning null?

EDIT:
I've just looked at an older similar crash in one of my other widgets. This is the Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.util.Base64.decode (Base64.java:120)
  at appname.LW01WidgetProvider.onUpdate (LW01WidgetProvider.java:202)
  at es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetProvider.onUpdate (HomeWidgetProvider.java:24)
  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive (AppWidgetProvider.java:66)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4748)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:309)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2279)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8582)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:563)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

This again indicates line 202 of the LW01WidgetProvider - but there is no line 202 in that file?

Comment: The line numbers could be off if the app is obfuscated (Proguard or R8). It's clear it's coming from `Base64.decode` though, so probably `widgetData.getString("dayfiveIcon", null)` is returning null. Maybe a good idea to get that string first and add a null check before attempting to decode it.

Comment: You can also take a look at the source code for Base64 at line 120 [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Base64.java#120) - definitely could fail with that error if the input string is null

Comment: Thanks. I've updated and included a null check in the widget provider. I check for null in my code before it gets to the widget provider, so ```widgetData.getString("dayfiveIcon", null)``` shouldn't be null, but there must be somewhere I've missed.